# Best way to authorization access some resource

Tags: java, authorization

User A and B exits in my service and there are several APIs.

- POST /item (for insert database)
- GET /item/{id} (for select database)
- DELETE /item/{id} (for delete data)

We use jwt to check if it is an approved user and if the user has permission to call API.
And we would like to prevent User B from requesting GET and DELETE for item id 1 registered by User A.

We check jwt at gateway. User B has jwt that we create and have permission to call api DELETE /item/{id} path.
When user B sends a DELETE /item/1 request, what is the best way to reject the request by authorization verification or not work api?

Answer (score 0):

You reject the request with status code [403 Forbidden](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/403). 401 Unauthorized is wrong, since you know who the user is.